# How to obtain consistently sign direction using rollcall and ideal from pscl package?

Tags: r, pscl

I'm using functions `ideal` and `rollcall` from `pscl` package but the same voters receive alternatively negative sign values or positive sign values depending (at list) on the ordering of the dataset. As I'm calculating this for several periods, I need its behavior to be consistent for every year.
Is there any way to control this aspect?

Comment: The problem is that in general this kind of model suffers from identifibility hence the same solution. Looks like with the `` constrain.legis`` arg you could set your most conservative person for -3 and least conservative for +3 and that should solve your sign issue.

Answer (score 1):

Okey, so looking at the documentation it looks like you can use the `priors` argument to specify which legislator you want to be your negative anchor and which one to be the positive anchor. See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pscl/pscl.pdf

Say for instance you know that legislator 1 is the most conservative and legislator 50 is the least conservative, you could make a matrix of means to use as priors. Based on the documentation anything you don't specify will use the default priors.

```
# 50 legislators
my_mean <- rep(0, 50)

my_mean[1] <- -3
my_mean[50] <- 3
```

Now when you go into the `ideal` function you can specify `xp` in the priors argument as below:

```
ideal(object, codes = object$codes,
dropList = list(codes = "notInLegis", lop = 0),
d = 1, maxiter = 10000, thin = 100, burnin = 5000,
impute = FALSE,
normalize = FALSE,
meanzero = normalize,
priors = list(xp = my_mean),  # Here, all defaults used for other args
startvals = "eigen",
store.item = FALSE, file = NULL,
verbose=FALSE, use.voter=NULL)
```

Without some data, I can't test it, but that should work. Additionally, instead of just fixing two persons you could have an ifelse statement and assign priors to a party:

```
my_mean <- ifelse(party == "Conservative", -3, 3)
```

Or something like this. I have an example of the above [here](https://michaeldewittjr.com/resources/stan_ideal_point.html), but it uses `rstan`.

Comment: During my first tries it didn't work.
I'm using during rollcall a character vector with names as "legis.names" parameter value and for this test, used a numeric vector as prior with all zeros values except elements with range position equal to legis.names corresponding to legislators I've seen as most extreme. I've toggled their values from -3 to +3, but the results are pretty similar, without sign change.